# How to upload and process a data set to Galaxy instance and retrieve results programmatically?

Tags: api, galaxy

How to upload and process (de novo assembly pipe) a data set to Galaxy instance and retrieve the results programmatically? Are there any packages beyond BioBlend?

Comment: Hi @player welcome. This question is way too general. There is a lot of expertise on de assembly, whether there is knowledge of you API is an issue. Please try and think of how to tie down your problem and describe it in more detail

Answer (score 1):

You best bet is bioblend, since it's a more convenient wrapper around the [Galaxy API](https://galaxyproject.org/develop/api/), but if you really want to you could use that directly. I should note that large files should probably still be uploaded via ftp or sftp rather than via the http(s) interface.

Comment: Perhaps you could include in the answer how to do this to improve the question?